# evaluating a self made function for a cector and then plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

i have created a function that represents a triangle sign.
this function does not work on vectors. i want to evaluate a vector x:

```
x=[-2:0.01:2]
```

and save the answer in vector y, for this purpose i came up with the following code:

```
for i=1:400, y(i) = triangle(x(i))
```

after i got the ans i plotted is using plot. in this case it worked ok but i am interested on observing the influence of time shifting and shrinking so when i try to use lets say:

```
for i=1:200, y(i) = triangle(x(2*i))
```

i get a vector y not the same length as vector x and i cant even plot them... is there any easy way to achieve it? and how should i plot the answer?

here is my function:

```
function [ out1 ] = triangle( input1 )
if abs(input1) < 1,
    out1 = 1 - abs(input1);
else 
    out1 = 0;
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

`y` is a different length in each `for` loop because each loop iterated a different number of times.  In the example below, I use the same `for` loops and plot y2 with the corresponding values of x. `i` is already defined in matlab so I've changed it to `t` in the example below.

```
clear all
x=[-2:0.01:2];

for t=1:400
    y(t) = triangle(x(t));
end

for t=1:200
    y2(t) = triangle(x(2*t));
end
```

Or, if you want to see y2 plotted over the same range you can increase the size of x:

```
clear all
x=[-2:0.01:8];

for t=1:400
    y(t) = triangle(x(t));
end

for t=1:400
    y2(t) = triangle(x(2*t));
end

plot(x(1:length(y)),y,'r')
hold on
plot(x(1:length(y2)),y2,'b')
```

Comment: hello and thank you for your answer, when i type `plot(x,y,'r')` it gives me an length error since y is of length 400 and x is of length 401, but its not biggi i used the x(1:length(y)), the real problem is when i try to plot the second `plot(x(1:length(y2)),y2,'b')` it shows the peak of the triangle at -1 because it simply squeeze the plot and instead of giving me the sclae from -2 to 2 it gives me -2 to 0, so i guess it doesnt work 100%, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: hey, the main problem is that the second plot doesnt give the right answer, it shrinks the scale instead of shrinking the answers spread. any idea how to handle it?

Comment: I see what you're saying, you probably don't want to plot y2 versus x but versus the values of x(t*2). This will give you an under sampled version of the original.  Or you can change the x values like this: plot([-1:0.01:2.99],y2,'b') It depends on what you're trying do here.